# Field "REF" is unknown in ADBC statement

Tags: abap, opensql

I'm having trouble using [ABDC](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenadbc.htm).

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
DATA:
      gr_sql_result_set TYPE REF TO cl_sql_result_set,
      gr_sql_statement  TYPE REF TO cl_sql_statement.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  CREATE OBJECT gr_sql_statement.

  gr_sql_result_set = gr_sql_statement->execute_query( 'SELECT VBELN ERDAT ERNAM AUDAT VKORG FROM VBAK' ).
  gr_sql_result_set->set_param_table( itab_ref = REF # ( gt_orders_head ) ).
```

The problem lies in `gr_sql_result_set->set_param_table`. The `REF #` statement gives me the following error: `Field "REF" is unknown. It is neither in one of the specified tables nor defined by a "DATA" statement.`

Is it possibile that I don't have the right version of SAP-ABAP installed which supports this statement?

Note: `gt_orders_head` is defined as `gt_orders_head TYPE TABLE OF zordhead_str`.
`zordhead_str` is a structure that I defined/created in Transaction `S11`.

---

I'm currently using SAP_BASIS Release 731

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor expressions like `REF` require SAP_BASIS 7.40 or later. So you can not use them in your 7.31 system until you update.

In the meantime you will have to work with a temporary reference variable instead:

```
DATA gt_order_head_ref LIKE REF TO gt_orders_head.
GET REFERENCE OF gt_orders_head INTO gt_order_head_ref.
gr_sql_result_set->set_param_table( itab_ref = gt_order_head_ref ).
```